# How to handle offline aggregation using Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been scouring the internet for days on a solution to this problem.

That is, how to handle aggregation when there is no network connection? I have a task management app that looks to aggregate meta data about user tasks. For example, the task can contain tags that can be aggregated to be shown in a dashboard to the user on a daily basis. This would be easy if the user is always online, so I could use transaction or cloud function to aggregate, but when the user is offline, the aggregation will appear to be incorrect, until the user restores their network connection.

Aggregation queries are explained here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation

Which states a limitation:

> Offline support - Client-side transactions will fail when the user's
> device is offline, which means you need to handle this case in your
> app and retry at the appropriate time.

However, there has yet to be any example or documentation on how to 'handle this case'. How would I go about addressing this problem?

Some thoughts:

1. I could cache the item if a transaction fails. This item will be aggregated on top of the stored aggregation. However, going down this line would mean that I can't take advantage of the Firestore's "offline mode", because I'm using my own cache on every write while offline anyway.
2. I could aggregate on demand. That is, never store the aggregation. This is going to be very heavy on read depending on how many tasks a user has. Furthermore, if the aggregation will need to be shared as insights to other users, this option will not work because other users do not have access to the tasks.

I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and trial and error I found a solution that can address this problem gracefully.

[FieldValue.increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#increment) to the rescue.

What FieldValue.increment does is bypass the use of transaction while respecting the default Firestore's offline cache behaviour. It requires the use of set or update on the field directly. The drawback is the inability to use the 'withConverter' on the collection for type safety. I'm willing to live with the drawback considering how useful FieldValue.increment is.

I've done multiple tests and can confirm that the values can be incremented/decremented multiple times locally while offline. This offline value is reflected in a get or snapshot call to the cache. When the network connection is restored, the values are updated on the server.

The value itself is not stored on the cache, it simply stores the "difference" in the FieldValue sentinel for when it is time to update it on the server.

This method only works with incrementing and decrementing values. Storing averages will not be possible using this method. That is because the true total number of items is not known at the time of its calculation when offline.

Instead, the total number of items are stored along side the total value. The average is then calculated when and as needed. In this way the average will always be accurate from a local perspective when offline, and it will also be accurate when online when the total value and count has been synced.